# Balls and bins - picking drawing one ball from each bin and calculating probability that all balls are black

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, balls-in-bins

> Assume we have $3$ bins: bins $L_1, L_2, L_3$, in each bin, there are $3$ balls. Alice is picking one ball from each bin at random. The balls can be either white or black. Alice does not know how many black or white balls are in each bin. She only knows the total number of black balls (denoted as $B$) and white (denoted as $W$) in the bins. Let's assume that the total number of black balls is $6$. We want to compute the probability that all selected balls are black (let's denote it $p$).

Intuitively, the distribution of white and black balls can end up as follows:

Case 1:

- $L_1$ has $B = 1 $,
- $L_2$ has $B = 2$,
- $L_3$ has $B = 3$

or, Case 2:

- $L_1$ has $B = 2$
- $L_2$ has $B = 2$
- $L_3$ has $B = 2$

Case 3:

- $L_1$ has $B = 3$
- $L_2$ has $B = 3$
- $L_3$ has $B = 0$

Thus, the total probability of picking only black balls is
$$ p = (\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot 1) + (\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3}) + 0 = 0.5185$$
Is the above correct?

Q2: In the second case (when each box has an equal number of black balls) Alice has the highest chances to pick only black balls (which is $0.2962$), so this is her "best-case scenario", while the $p = 0.5185$ is the total probability given that Alice cannot predict a-priori how the black balls will be distributed among the bins. Is the total probability considered an "average case" or should the average-case be computed differently?

**EDIT:**

Following the guidance in the comments, here is an updated version:

Assume we have $n$ balls and $k$ bins. $B$ balls are black, $W = n - B$ balls are white. We assigned the balls uniformly at random into the bins in such a way that each bin has $x = \frac{n}{k}$ elements ($k|n$). Once the balls are in the bins we pick from each bin one ball uniformly at random. What is the probability that all $k$ selected balls will be black?
Let $F$ be an event that all balls are black, and let $B_i$ denote the number of black balls in the $i'th$ bin.
From the total probability we can define it as follows:

$$
Pr(F) = \sum_{b_1 + b_2 + \ldots b_k = B} Pr(F | B_1 = b_1, \ldots B_k = b_k)\cdot Pr(B_1 = b_1, \ldots B_k = b_k)
$$

The first probability component is
$$ Pr(F | B_1 = b_1, \ldots B_k = b_k) = \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{b_i}{x} $$

The second is
$$
Pr(B_1 = b_1, \ldots B_k = b_k) = \frac{B!W!}{b_1!\cdot b_2! \cdot \ldots \cdot b_k! w_1! \cdot w_2! \cdot \ldots \cdot w_k!} \cdot \frac{(x!)^k}{n!} \\
= \frac{B!(n-B)!}{\prod_{i=1}^k b_i!\cdot(x-b_i)!}\cdot \frac{(x!)^k}{n!}
$$

Combining the two together we get
$$
(*) \quad 
Pr(F) = \sum_{b_1 + b_2 + \ldots b_k = B} \left( \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{b_i}{x} \cdot \frac{B!(n-B)!}{\prod_{i=1}^k b_i!\cdot(x-b_i)!}\cdot \frac{(x!)^k}{n!}\right)
$$

Is that correct?

Also, there was a lot of discussion in the comments that the problem which I described is equal to asking: given $n$ balls, where $B$ are black and $W$ are white if I pick $k$ balls what is the probability that all of them are black. This probability would be defined as
$$ (**)\quad 
Pr(F) = \frac{{B \choose k}}{{n \choose k}}
$$
I totally agree with the given examples, that it is the same value. However, this means the formulas $(*)$ and $(**)$ should be equal. I tried to simplify the formula (*) but I couldn't get what is in $(**)$. Is there something wrong with $(*)$?

Comment: Not every case you listed is equally likely. But it shouldn't matter. All that matters is that Alice selects 3 random balls.

Comment: @nicola Can you please clarify a bit?

Comment: That the bin thing is a red herring. Imagine that she select the 3 balls from just one bin with 6 black and 3 white balls. How is that different from the scenario you described?

Comment: Well, ok, I could describe it that way, but my experiment is that she picks 1 from each bin, and bins are labeled. I guess with one bin it would be us if the three bins are unlabeled?

Comment: If you have a card deck, what's the probability that the first card is the Ace of spades? Does this probability change if you select the 35th card? Or if you put 13 cards in 4 bins and select the 8th card of the second bin?

Comment: To make things more explicit: imagine Alice has 6 black balls and 3 white balls. First scenario: she selects straight up 3 balls. Second scenario: she randomly puts 3 balls in each of 3 labeled bins; than she randomly extracts one ball from each bin. Do you think that the probability of extracting 3 black balls is different between the two scenarios?

Comment: It's 1/52, no matter whether I'm picking the first one or the 35th card. So I guess what you're trying to say is that given 9 balls in total, among which 6 if I pick 3 balls at random the probability of picking all black, would be $(6 \choose 3) / (9 \choose 3)$. But I don't understand whether you're saying that my total case is wrong (and if yes - why)?

Comment: Yes, your probability in the last comment is correct. Now *you*, knowing the right answer, have to figure out what was wrong in your first attempt (Hint: black balls distributing 3/2/1, or 2/2/2 or 3/3/0 are not equally likely).

Comment: @nicola I think I see now: the distribution 3/2/1 happens with probability 6/10 (1/2/3, 1/3/2, 2/1/3, 2/3/1, 3/2/1, 3/1/2), the distribution 2/2/2 happens with probability 1/10 and the distribution 3/3/0 happens with probability 3/10 (3/3/0, 0/3/3, 3/0/3). Thus, I should add those factors in my calculation of the total probability. Is that correct?

Comment: Not quite. Take for instance the specific 3/1/2 distribution and the specific 3/0/3 distribution. They are not equally likely

Comment: @nicola I sadly don't see why those two individual distributions would have a different probability of occurring (assuming balls are assigned at random)?

Comment: Say there are just two bins. Do you still think that the 6/0 distribution is as likely to the 3/3 distribution? (Try to draw random balls to fill the bins and see what happens.)

Comment: @nicola I'm still confused. How can I split 9 balls into 2 bins with an equal number of balls? Do you mean in your example that we don't distinguish black and white balls, and just have 6 balls of the same color and assign them at random to two bins?

Comment: @nicola Since I couldn't fit in the comment I updated the original post with a new calculation of $p$, where I take into account a probability of a given distribution to occur. Is it now correct in your opinion? I feel like I'm still missing something but I'm not sure what

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about 12 balls (6W, 6B) to put into two bins. The 6/0 distribution is less likely than the 3/3 distribution. Didn't check your last edit, but it seems that you are on the correct track now. But the most important thing in this case I think is realizing that there is no difference between directly select 3 balls or extracting them from the bins. If you consider the bins, things become unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @nicola If you can check whether my last edit is correct, that would be great! regarding what you said about directly selecting balls vs extracting from the bins I'm trying to understand that, but I'm not sure I see your point. Maybe you can write an answer with an example showing why it ends up to be the same?

Comment: The question is: are the bins filled randomly or the distribution of the balls inside them is known? In the former case there is no difference between choosing from 3 bins with 3 balls in each or from 1 bin with 9 balls.

Comment: @user The bins are filled randomly (but each bin has an equal number of balls). So in my example, I have $9$ balls, (step 1) I randomly choose $3$ balls and put them into the first bin, then select again random $3$ balls and put them in the second bin, and put the remaining $3$ in the last bin. Next, (step 2) I pick from each bin a single ball and ask what is the probability that all selected balls are black? And I want to compute the total probability (i.e., take into consideration all possible distributions of black balls among the three bins) of always picking only black balls in step 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of getting exactly three black balls is given by:

$$
P(\text{3 B}) = \frac{6\choose 3}{9\choose 3} \simeq 0.2380952
$$

and it's the same of course of what Alice had if she extracts the 3 balls directly from a unique bin of 9 balls.

---

The bin subdivision doesn't affect the probability and it is obvious if you look at the following way. Imagine that Alice extracts one ball at the time, without looking, and "rank" the balls as the order of extraction. The "free" extraction corresponds in selecting balls 1,2,3; the "bins" extraction corresponds in selecting balls 1,4,7 after putting 1,2,3 on the first bin, 4,5,6 on the second and 7,8,9 on the third. It's obvious that the probability of having 3 blacks does not change.

However, if you really insist in starting with bins, things get unnecessarily complicated and tedious, because you have to calculate the probability of each bin composition. So, let's start assuming balls are numbered 1 to 9, and, as above, 1-2-3 belong to the first bin and so on. Next, we think at the "positions" of the white balls (easier to visualize, being less); there are ${9\choose 3} = 84$ different combinations they might assume. Now, we see how many of this combinations belong to the 1/2/3, 2/2/2 or 3/3/0 bin distribution.

Let's start with 2/2/2, which is easier. A white ball must stay in position 1,2 or 3; another in 4,5 or 6 and the last in 7,8 or 9. In total, you have $3\cdot 3\cdot 3 = 27$ combinations and so:

$$
P(2/2/2) = \frac{27}{84} \; .
$$

Now, we consider the 3/3/3 distribution. Now there are just 3 combinations of white balls that allow it, and namely 1-2-3, 4-5-6 and 7-8-9. So we have:

$$
P(3/3/0) = \frac{3}{84} \; .
$$

For the 3/2/1, we see that there are 6 of them, by permuting 1,2 and 3. For the specific 1/2/3 distribution we have that the first white ball must stay either in position 1,2 or 3; the other two must stay between ball 4 and 6, leaving a black ball that can be stay in any three of the remaining spot. So it means that you have $6\cdot 3 \cdot 3 = 54$ combinations for 3/2/1 and so:

$$
P(3/2/1) = \frac{54}{84} \; .
$$

Now we can go ahead and calculate your desired probability:

$$
P(\text{3 B}) = P(2/2/2) \cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3 + P(3/2/1)\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}
$$

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation! I've read it and I think I understand it. If I may ask the last thing: I found here: https://brilliant.org/wiki/multinomial-coefficients/ that the multinomial coefficient describes the number of ways to put $n$ objects into $k$ bins, such that bin $i$ has $b_i$ objects. So $n=6$, $k=3$ and the number of ways to put the black balls into the bins such that I have distribution $3/2/1$ would be $ 6! / (1! \cdot 2! \cdot 3!) = 60$. Hence, it is different than the number of combinations that you mentioned. From where does this difference come?

Comment: Why do you think that those multinomial coefficients are relevant here? (Hint: for a multinomial every bin is always available and so you could end up with a 5/1/1, or 4/2/0 or even 6/0/0 distributions; here your bins are constrained to have 3 balls.)

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right! So just getting back to your post - if I understand correctly even in a general case, when I have $n$ balls ($b$ black and $w = n-b$ white) and $k$ bins, and each bin has $x = \frac{n}{k}$ elements, when I choose $1$ ball from each bin, the probability that all $k$ balls will be black is the same as just picking $k$ balls out of $n$ balls?

Comment: I updated my post and tried to define the probability of an event that all balls are black in a more general case, both if I take bins into account and not. Can you please check it?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the bins are filled randomly.
Then the probability of the cases are the following:

1. $(3,2,1):\quad 6\times \frac{\binom63\binom30}{\binom93}\frac{\binom32\binom31}{\binom63}=\frac9{14}$
2. $(2,2,2):\quad 1\times\frac{\binom62\binom31}{\binom93}\frac{\binom42\binom21}{\binom63}=\frac9{28}$
3. $(3,3,0):\quad 3\times\frac{\binom63\binom30}{\binom93}\frac{\binom33\binom30}{\binom63}=\frac1{28}$

Correspondingly the probability to pick only the black balls is:
$$
\frac9{14}\frac33\frac23\frac13+\frac9{28}\frac23\frac23\frac23=\frac5{21}.
$$

The same probability one would obtain if the balls were drawn directly from a bin with 9 balls:
$$
\frac69\frac58\frac47=\frac5{21},
$$
which was clear also without any calculation.

---

EDIT:

In general the number of ways to fill the boxes with $b_1,b_2,\dots b_k$ black balls and $w_1,w_2,\dots w_k$ white balls is:
$$
\frac{b!}{b_1!b_2!\cdots b_k!}\frac{w!}{w_1!w_2!\cdots w_k!}
$$

Comment: Thanks! I get your calculation, I will just repeat the question I asked to the other answer. I found here: brilliant.org/wiki/multinomial-coefficients that the multinomial coefficient describes the number of ways to put  objects into  bins, such that bin  has  objects. So =6, =3 and the number of ways to put the black balls into the bins such that I have distribution 3/2/1 would be 6!/(1!⋅2!⋅3!)=60. Hence, it is different than the number of combinations that you mentioned. From where does this difference come?

Comment: The difference comes from the fact that you should choose the white ball(s) as well. In your particular example it is the second box where we put 2 black balls. There are 3 ways to choose the absent white ball which triples the number of possible combinations - $180$.

Comment: But does it matter which white balls will go there? I.e., isn't it ok to assume that a white ball will go there, but it doesn't matter which one of the white ones?

Comment: It does matter for correct computation of the probability.

Comment: I see. In a more general case: let's say I have $n$ balls in total, $B$ black and $W$ white ($B+W = n$) and I split them among $k$ bins uniformly at random, and each bin has $x = \frac{n}{k}$ balls. How in such a general case do I define the probability of the given distribution of black balls in bins, i.e., the probability that first bin has $b_1$ black balls, second $b_2$, and third $b_3$, such that $b_1 + b_2 + b_3$ = B$, and $b_i \geq 1$ for each $i $?

Comment: Can you explain a bit how did you derive it? I tried a bit on my own, but then got lost: I first draw $x$ balls for the first bin, the number of combinations is $$\frac{(B \choose b_1)(W \choose x-b_1)}{(n \choose x)}$$, then for the second bin it will be  $$\frac{(B-b_1 \choose b_2)(W - (x-b_1) \choose x-b_2)}{(n-x \choose x)}$$. Then if I'm correct for the $k-1$'th bin the number of combinations is $$\frac{(B - (b_1 + ... + b_{k-2}) \choose b_{k-1})(W - (k-2)x + b_1 + ... b_{k-2}\choose x-b_{k-1})}{(n - (k-2)x \choose x)}$$. Is this how you got your formula?

Comment: This nothing else as your own formula corrected by the fact that black and white balls are to be treated on the equal ground ($w_i=x-b_i$ is the number of white balls in the $i$-th box).

Comment: Sorry, latex didn't work in the comment. Can you please add the corrected formula in your answer post?

Comment: Regarding your edit: You added the calculation of the number of ways to fill the $k$ boxes so that i'th box has $b_i$ black balls and $w_i$ white (and $b_i + w_i = n/k$). But my original question was what is the general probability of getting this split?

Comment: To obtain the probability just divide the obtained number by the total number of ways to fill the boxes $$\frac {n!}{(x!)^k}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, following your guidance, I updated my original post to define the general formula for calculating the probability that all balls are black. Can you please check whether it is correct?

Comment: Accept what, your sentence is missing the ending :)

Comment: I think you'd better to accept an answer and post a new question rather than permanently  change the existing one.